# Excel | SLA for Report that's due at 1am | Charting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

We have a client report that has an SLA of 1am. The earliest the data is available to run the report is 11pm, so, we know that a report time between 1:01am and 10:59pm has missed the SLA).

I have one column with the date and another column with the report arrival time. I'd like to make a chart that shows the dates and the delta against the 1am SLA. Basically, an X-axis that shows a 1am plotted line with the delta above the line when the SLA is met and the delta below the line when the SLA is missed.

I'm running into several issues...one of the most basic issues is: I can't figure out how to get the delta, since we have the situation where 3 Sept 2023 at 12:52 makes the SLA, but 3 Sept 2023 8:51pm misses the SLA.

Thank you in advance for any guidance. I've included a few data points below as examples.

Apologies that the data below didn't stay in it's orginal format. I've included a visual, as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fldNB.png)

```
01/03/23    00:05:43    Made
01/04/23    01:06:00    MISSED
01/05/23    00:55:48    Made
01/06/23    00:22:56    Made
01/10/23    00:23:20    Made
01/11/23    00:19:21    Made
01/12/23    00:29:07    Made
01/13/23    00:13:50    Made
01/13/23    23:49:40    Made
01/17/23    00:05:36    Made
01/18/23    00:30:21    Made
01/19/23    00:12:12    Made
01/20/23    00:20:14    Made
01/21/23    00:10:59    Made
01/24/23    00:33:37    Made
01/24/23    23:49:52    Made
01/26/23    00:10:48    Made
01/26/23    23:49:56    Made
01/27/23    23:13:23    Made
01/31/23    00:14:37    Made
02/01/23    00:14:48    Made
02/02/23    02:20:16    MISSED
02/03/23    00:13:30    Made
```

Comment: Please edit your post to define `Delta`, and show what the results would be given your posted data.